# How to get selected optgroup value in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

With my application, i want to get the selected optgroup value in an select dropdown.

Here is the code

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model='theModel'   ng-change="display(theModel)" >
        <optgroup ng-repeat='group in collection' label="{{group.Name}}">
        <option ng-repeat='veh in group.Fields'>{{veh.Name}}</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Controlelr:**

```
$scope.display = function(name) {
       alert(name); // i want to get the selected value and the optgroup value
}
```

**[DEMO APP](https://plnkr.co/edit/V5GFX2zNp0Lc71szCdKj?p=preview)**

**OUTPUT REQUIRED:**
I want to display the selected optgroup value , if i select Field1 under Collection 1, i need Collection1.Field1

Comment: can u elaborate the question ? It's un clear what u need.

Comment: well cheers then @abhinsit has answered your question correctly

Comment: Can you please check my answer now ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the values in options to keep a reference of group and values as well. If the values in groups would have been unique then we could have used a value to group map in controller variable and would have got any data from there. But since same values reside in group, i have kept a reference of group in opt values and have used that.

**Now text shown in select box is what is desired and values of options are updated to keep a reference of group. So both are available now.**

**Updated Plunkr**: https://plnkr.co/edit/zvNcdDe0kmMJ1R67hOkK?p=preview

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.collection = response.data.Collections;
      console.log(response);
    });

    $scope.matches = [];

    $scope.display = function(name) {

       alert("controller:"+name.split("::")[0]+" and value ::"+name.split("::")[1] );
    }

  }
]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model='theModel' ng-change="display(theModel)">
    <optgroup ng-repeat='group in collection' label="{{group.Name}}">
    <option ng-repeat='veh in group.Fields' value='{{group.Name}}::{{veh.Name}}'>{{veh.Name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: Yes i got it a bit wrong updating my answer accordingly in few minutes

Comment: Can you please check if this is required

Comment: even though it displays, this is not what i require, i have to use the same fields rather than appending and displaying as option

Comment: I will update that also, but now my answer does not deserve a negative vote at least, would request you to please update that.

Comment: @abhinst, bro i did not downvote, i will add an upvote now

Comment: Updated the plunkr again, now this shows correct text in selectbox and set value in options with a reference to group